# How manually add row to index in Sphinx Search?

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

We have MariaDB, and Sphinx search engine.
One of tables have large data. And current max_doc_id 849826469. But somebody added rows with IDs less then `max_doc_id`. I can't change ID because it use in foreign indexes, and now we have much related data.

So this row doesn't add to index, but it should.

How I can do it?

```
source srcmos
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = 127.0.0.1
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db          = dev_db
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_query_pre   = REPLACE INTO sphinx_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM mos

    sql_attr_uint   = campaign_id
    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM mos WHERE id <= ( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sphinx_counter WHERE id=1 )
    sql_range_step  = 10000
    sql_query       = SELECT mos.id, campaign_id, body FROM mos WHERE mos.id>=$start AND mos.id<=$end
}
```

Comment: You should provide additional info about Sphinx indexing in your setup.

Comment: @hank, post updated

Comment: You can't add anything incrementally to a plain Sphinx index. Just reindex it.

Comment: @hank very sad:))

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a 32bit install.  Will need a 64bit install. A version with id64 in the build version

Comment: I add additional info